# dhcp client failure in latest version

Tags: c++, linux, dhcp, dhclient

To Configure dhcp ipv6 in my application I am using below mentioned command. Same command is getting executed in `dhcp version 4.2.5-P1`. But my application has dhclient version 4.3.0. And command cause failure for execution.
So Can any one guide me on this? What difference will be there in both version?

```
dhclient -6 -pf /var/run/udhcpc6.eth0.pid eth0 -e hostname:"ubuntu" -nw
```

Comment: Is not clear what is stack trace error. You can consult bugzilla for some reported errors. Also, see release notes for this version.

Comment: @user1929959 : I have read its release note but there isn't any specific change mentioned regarding previous version and current one.